# Hard to explain, angle and rectangle involved

Tags: c#, wpf, gradient, trigonometry

I have a rectangle and an angle. I need to provide the start and end points of a **`LinearGradientBrush`** in C# so that the **gradient** always fits perfectly within this rectangle and never under or over-extends the rectangle.

Could some of you mathletes out there help me out? I'm sure there's a really simple solution to this.

Comment: Question is too vague to answer. It isn't clear where the angle is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Tom W: Actually i for one know exactly what is being meant. You have to think of the start and end points and where they should be placed if the gradient is rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work (I am unable to test it):

```
var myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(Color.Red, Color.Black, myAngle);
myBrush.StartPoint = new Point(myRectangle.X, myRectangle.Y);
myBrush.EndPoint = new Point(myRectangle.X+myRectangle.Width, myRectangle.Y+myRectangle.height);
```

Comment: Thanks, I really should have checked for an overload accepting an angle. new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height), Color.Red, Color.Black, myAngle); works perfectly